# JPA. How to ignore some field only on merge operation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge

I would like to have fields: `creationDate` and `updateDate` in `Entity`,

I would like to this fields to be updated in db on `persist` operation.
But I would like to field `creationDate` will not be updated on `merge` operation in db.

I am looking for JPA annotation like this:
`@TransientOnMerge` or `@IgnoreOnMerge`
But cant find anything.

Is it possible?
Can You help?

Comment: The answer is also here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917148/jpa-columnupdatable-false-on-manytoone-related-field/29917204#29917204

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can add  @Column(updatable=false) to the field of the entity.

Comment: If it will work It will resolve my problem. I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: This does not work all the way.
With the `updatable = false` setup, the managed instance passed back from `merge` function still has these values overwritten. The ignoring only happens on the DB level.
I'd like to get the updated version of the instance. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [JPA EntityListener](http://www.javabeat.net/jpa-entity-listeners-callback-methods/) and update your dates on `@PrePersist` or `@PostPersist`

> PrePersist: This callback method is invoked for a given entity before
>   the respective Entity Manager executes persist operation for that
>   entity.
>
> PostPersist: This callback method is invoked for a given entity after
>   the respective Entity Manager executes persist operation for that
>   entity.

Comment: It is good way. On `@PreUpdate` method I could get from db `creationDate`  and set it for object before update. Which effect will be correct. But `@Column(updatable=false) is a better way I think.