# JPA. @Column(updatable=false) on @ManyToOne related field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, many-to-one

In my auditable entities I have field `creationUser` which I would like to not update in db on `merge` operation.

Here is my entity code:

```
@Column(updatable=false) 
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
public User creationUser;
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Unexpected exception
PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: defaultPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: models.AreaOfMedicine.creationUser
```

So how can I prevent from updating that field?
Please help

Comment: The error message tells you that `@Column` and `@ManyToOne` can't be specified together in this case. Remove `@Column`!

Comment: I can read what was the problem. I dont wanna remove that annotation, cause I need it. Your solution Is not a solution at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `@JoinColumn(updatable = false)` instead of `@Column(updatable = false)`.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes :D

Comment: What if it is a `@OneToMany` ?

Comment: `@OneToMany` would have the join column on the other side of the relationship.